# Getting Axios Error, status code 400 when trying to implement Oauth with nodejs and react

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, pkce

```js
import axios from "axios";
import "dotenv/config";
import { Router } from "express";
const authRouter = Router();


let codeVerifier: string = ""; // Initialize codeVerifier as an empty string

authRouter.post("/codeVerifier", (req, res) => {
  const { code_verifier } = req.body; // Assuming the code_verifier is sent in the request body

  if (!code_verifier) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "code_verifier not provided in the request body" });
  }

  // Assign the received code_verifier to the codeVerifier variable
  codeVerifier = code_verifier;

  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "code_verifier received successfully",
    code: codeVerifier, // Return the codeVerifier
  });
});



authRouter.get("/sessions/oauth/google", async (req, res) => {
  const { code, state } = req.query; // Get the authorization code and state from the query parameters

  if (!code) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Authorization code not found" });
  }

  try {
    // Exchange the authorization code, code verifier, and other parameters for tokens
    const tokenResponse = await exchangeCodeForTokens(code, codeVerifier);
    console.log(tokenResponse)
    return res.status(200).json(tokenResponse);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error("Error exchanging code for tokens:", error);
      return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});

// Function to exchange the authorization code for tokens with Google
async function exchangeCodeForTokens(
  authorizationCode: any,
  codeVerifier: string
) {

  console.log({
    code: authorizationCode,
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI, // Ensure this matches your setup
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code_verifier: codeVerifier,
  });
    const tokenUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
   
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(tokenUrl, null, {
      params: {
        code: authorizationCode,
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI, // Ensure this matches your setup
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code_verifier: codeVerifier, // Include the code_verifier in the request
      },
    });


    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw Error(error);
  }
}

export default authRouter;
```

I tried to console log every value as you can see, and every value is present and setting up perfectly, yet I am still not able to solve the bug, please help would be appreciated.

The basic flow is,

1. Generate Code_verifier and Code_challenge on the frontend (react), using useEffect on the first render I send the code_verifier to the backend for later use.
2. When user clicks on button, login with google, they get redirected to the consent screen.
3. when user accepts the conditions, the request is made to backend
4. and then i get 400 error.

This part of the code is producing the error.

```js
  async function exchangeCodeForTokens(
      authorizationCode: any,
      codeVerifier: string
    ) {

      console.log({
        code: authorizationCode,
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI, // Ensure this matches your setup
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code_verifier: codeVerifier,
      });
        const tokenUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
       
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(tokenUrl, null, {
          params: {
            code: authorizationCode,
            client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI, // Ensure this matches your setup
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code_verifier: codeVerifier, // Include the code_verifier in the request
          },
        });


        return response.data;
      } catch (error: any) {
        throw Error(error);
      }
    }

    export default authRouter;
```

The entire error is:

```js
Error exchanging code for tokens: Error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
    at /home/alucard/github/auth/backend/src/router/authRouter.ts:78:11
    at step (/home/alucard/github/auth/backend/src/router/authRouter.ts:33:23)
    at Object.throw (/home/alucard/github/auth/backend/src/router/authRouter.ts:14:53)
    at rejected (/home/alucard/github/auth/backend/src/router/authRouter.ts:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I tried the console log to check the credentials, and they all are getting sent correctly,

```js
{
  code: '4/0AfJohXkguxRKR_W0kr5pv4e2JE1UouZNkCw9OR0H8tca3_0Ul5j0RG1aeifOMQ-UqX2_Zg',
  client_id: //client_id,
  client_secret: //client_secret,
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/api/sessions/oauth/google',
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code_verifier: 'b67589d00ac9d3bbfb9be718cf88c0c2cdc7bbe1f206e16476913fee'
}
```

Comment: Which request is 400'ing. What is the console.log output for the failed request? Also share the frontend code doing this specific request. Also given that you have a backend service here I'd strongly recommend you take react out of the equation and handle the entire process in the backend but that's not a solution to your immediate problem.

Comment: @Evert I updated the question and added all the things you mentioned, in frontend the only thing I am doing Is sending the user to google consent screen when user clicks on a  button.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! When you get a 400 error from an OAuth2 server back, usually you also get a response body with more details on what went wrong. Can you take a look at that? Also you might like my client: https://github.com/badgateway/oauth2-client/tree/main

Comment: Also, one thing that is a risk with your backend code is that 2 people cannot go through the authentication process at the same time.  codeVerifier will get overwritten every time a person starts the process, so only use that setup in testing scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to console  log out the full Error and The Response too, but the response is just not showing up in console nor in the browser, I am not using any third party modules yet, cause I am trying to implement all this for just learning purposes.  I would also like some ideas on how you would send the codeVerifier to the backend.

Comment: The codeVerifier should never leave the backend! Ideally you redirect the user to your backend, and then the backend redirects to google with teh codeVerifier. The endpoint you built should not be needed. How are you logging the error response body?